# The Point of Tangency Between a Sphere and a Tangent Plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-curves, spheres

Find the equation of the sphere centered at (2,0,-3) that is tangent to the plane x=y.
 
**What is the point of tangency?** Describe the interior of the sphere with an inequality.

What I have thus far:
The Equation of a Sphere Format $(x-x_0)^2+(y+y_0)^2+(z+z_0)^2=(r)^2$
which is $(x-2)^2+(y)^2+(z+3)^2=(\sqrt2)^2$
I've tried finding the point by creating a parametric equation:
$r(t)=<2,0,-3>+t<1,-1,0>$ because the Equation of a Plane Format is $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$
So, x=y Plane is really $x-y=0$
With that, I have:
x(t)=2+t
y(t)=-t
z(t)=-3
I looked at similar problems but do not grasps all the steps, please be concise.

I proceeded with the advise point of tangency, but it doesn't correspond with my graph.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're alright here, the line you've created passes through the center of the sphere and is perpendicular to the plane $x=y$ (as it should be, since the tangent planes of the sphere are perpendicular to the vectors pointing from the center to a point on the sphere's surface).  Now you must find the point on that line which lies on a sphere with equation $(x-2)^2 + y^2 + (z+3)^2 = r^2$ and *also lies on* the plane $x = y$.  This is the point of tangency.

My trouble is seeing why you've assumed the sphere has radius $\sqrt{2}$, which is not obvious to me.  Leaving $r$ as a variable, we'll find the $r$ value which allows us to simultaneously solve $$ (x-2)^2 + y^2 + (z+3)^2 = r^2, ~~x=y, ~~ \textrm{ and } (x,y,z) = (2+t, -t, -3)$$
for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Plugging in our $x$, $y$, and $z$ values from the line's equation into the plane's equation we have 
$$ x = y \to 2+t = -t$$
which gives $t = -1$.  Now we solve for $(x,y,z) = (2+t, -t, -3) = (1,1,-3)$.  This point must be on the plane and your line, so this is the point of tangency!  We choose $r$ in order to make this point also lie on the sphere:

$$r^2 = (x-2)^2 + y^2 + (z+3)^2 = (1-2)^2 + (-1)^2 + (-3+3)^2 = 1 + 1, $$
$$ r^2 = 2 $$

so $r = \sqrt{2}$ as you stated before.  This gives us the equation for the sphere, and by rewriting it as 
$$ (x-2)^2 + y^2 + (z+3)^2 \leq 2$$
we find an inequality describing the sphere's interior.

Comment: I found the radius using the projection of vectors. I see now! x(t)=y(t) hence 2+t=-t. This makes sense! And I can solve for both at once. Why do you think it isn't corresponding with my graph?

Comment: Found it! The point of tangency is **(1,1,-3)**. Since t=-1, -t=1! Whoo! Thanks for help.

Comment: Your welcome :)

Comment: Edited the answer for *correctness.*